# Ruby - source code - coding style

Tags: c, ruby, coding-style

Looking through the Ruby code it has the following for proc_arity:

```
static VALUE
proc_arity(VALUE self)
{
    int arity = rb_proc_arity(self);
    return INT2FIX(arity);
}
```

More of a C coding style question really but why is `static VALUE` on a separate line instead of something like this:

```
static VALUE proc_arity(VALUE self)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It comes from the UNIX world, because it helps to easily `grep` the definition of a function:

```
$ grep -n '^proc_arity' *.c
```

or using `vim`:

```
/^proc_arity
```